# Turtlebot support in ROS2 Dashing

Tags: ros2, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
Do we have support for turtlebot2 or turtlebot3 For ROS2 dashing?
I found ROS2 demos for bouncy but I don't think they will work for Dashing.

I want to run teleoperator in ROS2 dashing, but could not find kobuki or turtlebot drivers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326512/turtlebot-support-in-ros2-dashing/) by [petal](https://answers.ros.org/users/35592/petal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2019-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have been prepared TurtleBot3 for Dashing.
It'll be released next month.

---

Originally posted by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) with karma: 811 on 2019-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [petal](https://answers.ros.org/users/35592/petal/) on 2019-06-21**:
So, Is there any other mobile robot whose drivers and packages have been developed and released for ROS Dashing?

**Comment by [petal](https://answers.ros.org/users/35592/petal/) on 2019-07-24**:
Hello!

Do we have any progress in turtlebot3 for dashing ?

**Comment by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) on 2019-07-25**:
Hello again! We are preparing Dashing release but there are some problems.
If you want to get lastest update about it. Please check our issue page.
https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/issues/426

**Comment by [petal](https://answers.ros.org/users/35592/petal/) on 2019-07-25**:
Thank you for the updates.